# How to install flexlay editor

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, make

I have got problem with installing program named flexlay editor. 
when I type ./configure there not making makefile.
message from configure shell script:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c 
checking whether build environment is sane... yes 
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p 
checking for gawk... no 
checking for mawk... mawk 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes 
checking for gcc... gcc 
checking whether the C compiler works... yes 
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out 
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no 
checking for suffix of object files... o 
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes 
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes 
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed 
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes 
checking for style of include used by make... GNU 
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3 
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes 
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes 
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib 
checking for main in -lqthreads... no
checking for scm_boot_guile in -lguile... no 
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E 
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep 
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E 
checking for ANSI C header files... yes 
checking for sys/types.h... yes 
checking for sys/stat.h... yes 
checking for stdlib.h... yes 
checking for string.h... yes 
checking for memory.h... yes 
checking for strings.h... yes 
checking for inttypes.h... yes 
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes 
checking guile/gh.h usability... no
checking guile/gh.h presence... no 
checking for guile/gh.h... no
checking for debug mode... enabled 
checking for maintainer mode... enabled 
checking for swig... /usr/bin/swig 
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config 
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes 
checking for EDITOR... no configure: error: Package requirements (
clanCore-0.7           >= 0.7.7   clanApp-0.7            >= 0.7.7  
clanDisplay-0.7        >= 0.7.7   clanGL-0.7             >= 0.7.7  
clanGUI-0.7            >= 0.7.7   clanGUIStyleSilver-0.7 >= 0.7.7   )
were not met:

No package 'clanCore-0.7' found 
No package 'clanApp-0.7' found 
No package 'clanDisplay-0.7' found 
No package 'clanGL-0.7' found 
No package 'clanGUI-0.7' found 
No package 'clanGUIStyleSilver-0.7' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables EDITOR_CFLAGS and
EDITOR_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config
man page for more details.
```

what is wrong with configure shell script?

Answer (score 1):

According to the `INSTALL` file located in the package top level

> To compile Flexlay you need a recent ClanLib 0.7, quite often the
>   latest not-yet-released development version from the subversion tree,
>   available at:
>
> - http://www.clanlib.org

It lists the following additional reqirements

> And you need scons (a make replacement) available at:
>
> - http://www.scons.org
>
> In addition to that Ruby, available at:
>
> - http://www.ruby-lang.org
>
> And for the games you need a recent copy of them, most often latest
>   development version of them is required.